# Graceful handling of ConditionCheckFailedException with DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

When using `ConditionExpression` in a DynamoDB request, and the condition is not met, the entire request will fail. I am using conditional updates, and the fact that ConditionCheckFailedException doesn't contain any information about which condition failed is giving me a hard time.

For example consider this scenario: There's an item in a table like this:

```
{
  state: 'ONGOING'
  foo: 'FOO',
  bar: 'BAR'
}
```

I then want to update this item, changing both `foo` and `state`:

```
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
  :STATE_FINISHED: 'FINISHED',
  :FOO: 'NEW FOO'
},
UpdateExpression: 'SET state=:STATE_FINISHED, foo=:FOO',
```

However, my application has a logical transition order of states, and to prevent concurrency issues where two requests concurrently modify an item and causing an inconsistent state, I add a condition to make sure only valid transitions of `state` are accepted:

```
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
  :STATE_ONGOING: 'ONGOING'
},
ConditionExpression: 'state = :STATE_ONGOING'
```

This e.g. prevents two concurrent requests from modifying state into FINISHED and CANCELLED at the same time.

This is all fine when there's only one condition; if the request fails I know it was because an invalid state transition and I can choose whether to just fail the request, or to make a new request that only modifies FOO, whatever makes sense in my application. But if I have multiple conditions in one request, it seems impossible to find out which particular condition failed, which means I need to fail the entire request or divide it into multiple separate requests, updating one conditional value at a time. This can however raise new concurrency issues.

Has anyone found a decent solution to a similar problem?

Ideally what I'd want is to be able to make a `UpdateExpression` that modifies a certain attribute conditionally, otherwise ignoring it, or by using a custom function that returns the new value based on the old value and the suggested updated value, similar to an SQL `UPDATE` with an embedded `SELECT .. CASE ...`. Is anything like this possible?

Or, is it at least possible to get more information out of a ConditionalCheckFailedException (such as which particular condition failed)?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the DynamoDB doesn't provide granular level error message if there are multiple fields available on `ConditionalExpression`. I am not addressing this part of the question in my answer.

I would like to address the second part i.e. returning the old/new value.

The `ReturnValues` parameter can be used to get the desired values based on your requirement. You can set one of these values to get the required values.

**New value** - should already be available

**Old value** - To get old value, you can either use **UPDATED_OLD** or **ALL_OLD**

```
ReturnValues: NONE | ALL_OLD | UPDATED_OLD | ALL_NEW | UPDATED_NEW,
```

> ALL_OLD - Returns all of the attributes of the item, as they appeared
> before the UpdateItem operation.
>
> UPDATED_OLD - Returns only the
> updated attributes, as they appeared before the UpdateItem operation.
>
> ALL_NEW - Returns all of the attributes of the item, as they appear
> after the UpdateItem operation.
>
> UPDATED_NEW - Returns only the updated
> attributes, as they appear after the UpdateItem operation.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, or vice versa, but my issue was that I want to update certain values conditionally, depending on their current (old value), otherwise ignoring updating them. In my example I would like to set status to FINISHED if the old value was ONGOING, but if the old value is CANCELLED I do not want to alter the value at all. Effectively this means setting the attribute to the value returned from a custom function taking both the new and the old value.

Comment: In some situations, using functions such as MIN, and having a set of pure integer values that correspond to "higher value has priority" could be used to achieve this. But in my example, I would like FINISHED and CANCELLED to be allowed values for an item currently being ONGOING, but FINISHED should never replace CANCELLED and vice versa.

Comment: For the first comment, I think you already have a solution in your answer itself. I thought you have two different conditions on conditional expression with AND operator and you wanted to know which condition got failed (this is not available on DynamoDB).#